# Prove an inequality in $\mathbb N^*$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

I can not to prove the following inequality 
 $$ \forall \, n\in \mathbb N^* : \quad \left(1- \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^n \left( 1+ \frac{1}{n} \right) < 1$$
I tried to use the recurrence, but I'm stuck.
Someone can help me!!!

Remarks: I need proof, to the level of a high school student.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Check that the inequality holds for $n=1$. For $n\geq 2$ Bernoulli's inequality implies that $$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{-(n+1)}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2-1}\right)^{n+1}>1+\frac{1}{n-1}$$ and so $$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n+1} < 1-\frac{1}{n}.$$ Divide both sides by $1-\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @ WimC, thanks for your answer, but I need proof, to the level of a high school student

Comment: Then take the binomial theorem, for $x\ge 0$ you have $(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$. More was not used.

Comment: This is a really nice proof!  I've used Bernoulli's Inequality several times in answers I've posted on MSE.  It is such an underrated inequality!  Well done!  +1